# Why do we use the Babylonian month names?

Tags: names, calendar, months

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use Babylonian calendar instead of our own?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/why-use-babylonian-calendar-instead-of-our-own)

The Torah refers to the months of the near numerically, the names we employ for things like contracts, birkat hachodesh etc. originate in Bavel. Why do we continue to use those names for the months instead of the ones in the Torah (I realize the anshei k'neses ha'gedolah canonized this practice, I'm looking to understand why).

[Slightly related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14830/first-temple-era-names-of-the-hebrew-months)