# Names of the days of the week

Tags: names, calendar

What are the Jewish names for each of the week days?

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14830/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43296/759

Comment: Is this just a Hebrew question? @DoubleAA

Answer (score 1):

The names are the numbers leading up to שבת the Sabbath

Sunday - Rishon - ראשון First
Monday - Sheni - שני Second
Tuesday - Shlishi - שלישי Third
wednesday - Rev-ee-ee - רביעי Fourth
Thursday - Hamishi - חמישי Fifth
Friday - Shishi - שישי Sixth also called Erev Shabbos ערב שבת Eve of Shabbat
Saturday - Shabbat - שבת

Comment: Friday is not called erev shabbos; Friday evening is. In the same way that Monday evening is erev yom shlishi, Wednesday evening is erev yom chamishi, Sunday evening is erev yom rishon, etc. Since the day starts when the sun has descended and the stars have come out (rather than at midnight), the evening of Shabbos is Friday night.

Comment: @ShimonbM IME Friday is called _erev Shabas_. See also the comments on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47386.

Comment: @ShimonbM And it is a mitzva to each all of Erev Yom Kippur, right from the morning.

Comment: You could add that the phrase "ohr l'yom..." (lit. light [that belongs] to day number...) means the night *before* the day in question.

Comment: Also, the name of the day is "yom (ha)rishon" etc. not just the numeral.

Comment: Adding sources to support your claims would increase this post's value.

Comment: Is Saturday really called _Shabbat_ and not _Yom HaShvi'i_? I understand you _can_ refer to the day by the holiday which happens to coincide with it every week, but is that the day's name?

Comment: @DoubleAA indeed the gemara [RH 31a](http://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.31a?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) calls the day *hashvii* - although  I can see how no one calls it this way in day to day language